# Redirecting from one html to another using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to perform a simple redirect where I redirect one html page to another *before* the following rules, that I already have in my `.htaccess` file are applied:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>`
```

I tried various stuff, like adding a simple

`redirect page1.html page2.html`

line after RewriteEngine and

`RewriteRule page1.html page2.html [R=301,L]`

but it didn't work.

Could you please tell me what line I should add to redirect from `page1.html` to `page2.html`?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you added the rule?

Comment: nothing actually same behavior as before

Comment: try it again but clear your browser cache after you do it. There shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: But is `RewriteRule page1.html page2.html [R=301,L]` actually correct?

Comment: Yes, that rule is very simple and should work.